# Foursquare API 405 Method Not Allowed?

Tags: foursquare

**Here is my code:**
This code is used angularjs but when I submit it got message error "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405"

```
$scope.listLocation = []; 
$scope.getLocation = function() {

        var time = Date.now();
        return  $http({
            method: "POST", 
            url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=11.5448729,104.8921668&client_id=.....&client_secret=......&v=1494294266811&limit=500&radius=500&intent=browse',
        }).then(function success(res) {
            $scope.listLocation = res.data.response.venues
        }, function error(res) {    

            return res;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to change your `method` from `"POST"` to `"GET"`, if you are just trying to retrieve data.

```
    $scope.listLocation = []; 
    $scope.getLocation = function() {

    var time = Date.now();
    return  $http({
        method: "GET", 
        url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=11.5448729,104.8921668&client_id=LP5KESHULNRR3BCNKBD3O1J1FNMWQ3RFRHN34SSLV0GPMQLV&client_secret=ZI5233EL5L5LVJZIVHWKWSCBUCX0HIQ3MUJAXIEYVWQGOJTR&v=1494294266811&limit=500&radius=500&intent=browse',
    }).then(function success(res) {
        $scope.listLocation = res.data.response.venues
    }, function error(res) {    

        return res;
    });
}
```

P.s., That `client_secret` query parameter looks sensitive.

Comment: It must be something other than the method and URL then. The following work for me:

`$ curl -is  "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=11.5448729,104.8921668&client_id=LP5KESHULNRR3BCNKBD3O1J1FNMWQ3RFRHN34SSLV0GPMQLV&client_secret=ZI5233EL5L5LVJZIVHWKWSCBUCX0HIQ3MUJAXIEYVWQGOJTR&v=1494294266811&limit=500&radius=500&intent=browse"  | head -n1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
`

Comment: but If I tried test via POSTMAN it worked as well, I don't know why

Comment: Oddly enough `curl -is -X POST $YOUR_URL | head -n1` gives me `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, but `curl -I $YOUR_URL | head -n1` gives me `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` (a `HEAD` request)

Comment: Your `v` parameter looks strange, should be a date like `20170101`. Idk if that is throwing something off? Also, you probably shouldn't post your `client_secret` here.